# ORACLE large data transfer between databases

Tags: database, oracle, import, export, data-transfer

So a bit of background for my question. I am migrating a clients data from one application to a newer version and have to map the data over which for most important tables they don't map identically from the old to the new.

At the moment we have links between both databases and transfer the data in this sort of format:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (col1, col2, col3, col4, ...)
SELECT COL1, COL2, NULL, col4, ...
FROM table_name@older_db
```

This works well for most small tables but for some tables measuring multiple dozens of GB one insert may take several hours. The only optimization I've tried so far is the APPEND hint and I'm not sure how much that even really helps.

Some of the constraints I have for transferring data over (aside from time of course) are that the client can't use manual tools such as TOAD export/import tools and possible space or hardware limitations.

Are there any Oracle/SQL exports that take custom datasets (as I said the tables don't map the same) that may be faster than my current method. I would appreciate any recommendations and references to how to use them in my context.

Comment: If table_name will only contain data from table_name@older_db, you could use
`create table table_name as 
SELECT COL1, COL2, NULL, col4)
FROM table_name@older_db;`

Comment: can you only do an insert or can you do create table and do as @runningviolent suggested?

Comment: Are you able to use Oracle's expdp and impdp?  If you can't use the utilities, could you use data pump over a network link?

Comment: @runningviolent I may be able to use create table from my query as described, this would be a significant increase on insert with select?

Comment: @JonHeller I can use any oracle command that can be automated but I don't believe data pump actually works over a link? can expdp/exp even take a custom dataset? Or does it need to be from a strict defined table?

Comment: @gfortin13 I have used this trick many times as a faster alternative to inserting. `create table as...` does not create undo information and I believe that is where you gain the speed. As an alternative to creating the table, maybe you could remove all the indexes on table_name and `INSERT /*APPEND parallel(table_name ,10) */ into table_name...`, then recreate the innexes. Please keep in mind that the `parallel` hint will only work in Enterprise Edition.

Comment: @gfortin13 Data pump does work over [network links](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_import.htm#BEHFCBEI).  A single database link is always slow and I've never found anyway to significantly increase performance.  However, the Data Pump API does allow parallel jobs over links.  Using a large number of parallel jobs may be able to significantly improve performance.